# Is there a way to apply hues along with a color in Angular2 Material?

Tags: angular2-material

Currently, in Angular Material, [you can differentiate a color](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/02_declarative_syntax) with e.g. `class="md-hue-1"`.  Any plans on doing something similar in Material2?  If not, any suggestions for a workaround?